# Count if 2d data contain non-zero element pairs

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

```
SeedRandom[1];
m = RandomInteger[1, {10, 2}]
Position[m, u_ /; u != {0, 0}]

{{1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, 
 {0, 1}, {1, 1}}

{{1}, {2}, {4}, {5}, {9}, {10}, {}}
```

I want to find where the pairs are different from `{0,0}`. What is the last emtpy bracket?

Comment: The empty brackets indicate that the entire expression matched the pattern, see the 5th point in the details section of the documentation of [`Position`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Position[m, u_ /; u != {0, 0}, 1]

{{1}, {2}, {4}, {5}, {9}, {10}}

Count[m, Except[{0, 0}]]

6
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[1];

m = RandomInteger[1, {10, 2}]
```

{{1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0,
1}, {1, 1}}

A few more possibilities

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Length @ Flatten[SequenceSplit[m, {{0, 0}}], 1]
```

6

Using `Counts`

```
Length[m] - Counts[m][{0, 0}]
```

6

Using `DeleteCases`

```
Length @ DeleteCases[{0, 0}] @ m
```

6

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[1];

m = RandomInteger[1, {10, 2}]

{{1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}
```

Using `SequencePosition`:

```
SequencePosition[m, {{OrderlessPatternSequence[Except[0], _]}}]

(*{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}, {9, 9}, {10, 10}}*)

Length@%

(*6*)
```

Or using `CountsBy` and `ContainsOnly`:

```
CountsBy[m, ! ContainsOnly[#, {0}] &][True]

(*6*)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `BitOr`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];

list = {{1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 
   0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}};

Map[Apply[BitOr]][list] // Count[1]
BitOr @@@ list // Count[1]
```

> 6

```
Map[Apply[BitOr]][list] // Position[1]
Position[BitOr @@@ list, 1]
```

> {{1}, {2}, {4}, {5}, {9}, {10}}

---

A minor variation using `Through`:

```
Through[{Count[1], Position[1]}[BitOr @@@ list]]
```

> {6, {{1}, {2}, {4}, {5}, {9}, {10}}}

---

For this particular case with `1` and `0` as sublist elements, this works. If there are other integers in sublists, then use `Unitize@list` to get ones and zeros prior to applying `BitOr`.

---

**Using `PositionIndex`:**

```
{Length@#, #} &@ (PositionIndex[list] // KeyDrop[{{0, 0}}] // Values //
    Apply[Union])
```

> {6, {1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 10}}